# MSI Modern 14 (Ryzen 5-4500u) BSOD

Tags: bsod, windows-11, windows-installer, amd-ryzen, microsoft

I was on Windows 11 v22H2 and received BSOD with stop code `CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED`; I restarted and, while working on a project, I received BSOD `UNEXPECTED_STORE_EXCEPTION`, followed by `KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR` within a few minutes, so I:

- rolled back the latest update, was still receiving BSODs with random stop codes, so I clean installed Win11, but no luck
- installed Win10 build 19044 hoping I wouldn't get BSODs, but am now getting `WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR` 20 - 30x a day during 6 - 8 hours of use, which gets stuck at 0% and then restarts: 
   [image: It get stuck at 0% and then restarts]

MemTest86 went through four passes with no errors, Windows Memory Diagnostics passed with no errors twice, `Chkdsk` returned no errors or bad sectors, and working in Safe Mode still results with BSODs.

After the BSODs, it directly goes to the UEFI firmware settings and I cannot find my internal SSD; however, when I exit the UEFI firmware settings, Windows boots without any issue.

- Device: MSI Modern 14 
   <sup>(All updates installed, drivers updated, and no external device connected)</sup>
- Processor: Ryzen 5 4500u
- RAM: Samsung 8GB-3200 DDR4
- Storage: 500 GB SSD
- Win Version : Win 10 build

Comment: There's an issue with one of the hardware components _(BSOD `WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR` is an acronym for Windows Hardware Error Architecture)_, and since the SSD isn't being found by the UEFI firmware, I'd start there by booting with the SSD disconnected _(boot an InstallUSB or Linux LiveUSB if it's the only drive)_. Googling the BSOD errors will provide additional troubleshooting steps, including for WHEA BSODs. If the motherboard has built-in UEFI firmware hardware diagnostics, running them should also pinpoint the error.

Comment: The analysis from WinDbg is helpful in a case like this since it will call out the driver responsible which will point to a specific hardware

Comment: @JW0914 Thank you, I'll try to use it with liveUSB with and without SSD connected to see if it helps or not. I tried googling first and I know WHEA is a stopcode for hardware errors, I've already tried MemTest86 and WMD but seems like there is no issue with my RAM.

Comment: @YogeshK. While [`WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x124---whea-uncorrectable-error) is a general hardware error, [`KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x7a--kernel-data-inpage-error) is hard drive related, typically indicating data couldn't be read because of a bad block [sector], and [`UNEXPECTED_STORE_EXCEPTION`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x154--unexpected-store-exception) often signals a driver error.

Comment: @YogeshK. _(Cont'd...)_ [`CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xef--critical-process-died) could be a range of things, requiring crash dump analysis w/ [WinDbg](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/crash-dump-files). Due to the RAM test not showing errors and `ChkDsk` showing no filesystem errors, likely cause is a hardware issue with the SSD _(if booting from another drive shows this as the issue, reseating the SATA cable on the drive and motherboard, or reinstalling if NVMe/mSATA, may resolve it)_

Comment: @JW0914 I used to get random stopcodes on Win11 but after installing Win10 I'm getting "WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE ERROR" only. Also, I cannot find any Dump file or folder I've checked all the settings and tried different Dump folder locations too but no luck may be because the process always stays at 0% and is never completed as you can see in the image attached. It's a laptop so there is no SATA cable but thankfully SSD & RAM both are removable.

Comment: @YogeshK. I recommend ruling out hardware before spending time analyzing dump files _(can be manually generated, but unless you can't find the hardware causing this, this would be time inefficient)_. Most laptops come with built-in BIOS or UEFI firmware hardware diagnostics usually accessible either from the BIOS/UEFI firmware boot options screen or from within the BIOS/UEFI firmware settings _(some OEMs also create a hotkey combo to hold down while turning the laptop on to directly boot to the hardware diagnostics)_ - if MSI includes this, run a system-wide long test _(takes >4hrs)_

Comment: @YogeshK. _(Cont'd...)_ LifeWire has a decent writeup on [How to Fix a Kernel Data Inpage Error](https://www.lifewire.com/fix-kernel-data-inpage-error-4689916), as well as a [list](https://www.lifewire.com/blue-screen-error-codes-4065576) of what each Stop Code numerical error means, which can also be found on [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-code-reference2#bug-check-codes) in more detail via each code's link